# Eclipse: How do I install Eclipse Web Developer Tools manually?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How do I install *Eclipse Web Developer Tools* using the `dropin` folder?

What do I need to download?

This is for Eclipse 3.6 Helios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *really* do not want to use the [Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliossr1) 'edition' which comes with web developer tools bundled you will find instructions on [this page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP/What_we_have_learned_%28to_love%29_about_P2). You can download the necessary packages and the prerequisites from [here](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/).